# Difference between Filter and Listener in Servlet (Java EE)

Tags: java, servlets, servlet-filters, servlet-listeners

There are Filters and Listeners functionality in Servlet. I want to know exact difference between Filter and Listener.

Answer (score 86, accepted):

Servlet Filter is used for monitoring request and response from client to the servlet, or to modify the request and response, or to audit and log.

Servlet Listener is used for listening to events in a web containers, such as when you create a session, or place an attribute in an session or if you passivate and activate in another container, to subscribe to these events you can configure listener in `web.xml`, for example `HttpSessionListener`.

Comment: And it is also worth nothing that listeners implements javax.servlet.ServletContextListener while filters implement javax.servlet.Filter

Comment: Can you pls clarify this for me? `ServletRequestListener` listens to `ServletRequestEvent` which is an event triggered for every incoming request. If I want to log the user-agent for every request to my web app, should I use this listener or a filter?

Comment: @BalusC Is defining a listener is mandatory? It gives me error `No WebApplicationContext found: no ContextLoaderListener registered?` if I do not define a listener in my Spring application.

Comment: hmm, i don't really get why you would need to listen for when a session is created or listen for when an attribute in a session is created. Can you give an example on when you've used a listener in any applications you've developed?

Answer (score 38):

Filters are used for pre and post process requests. Look at the `javax.servlet.Filter` in your
tomcat/jboss/other container javadoc.

Where as the listeners are like triggers that can be attached to events in
your app server (let's use the term container here). With listeners you can track application-level, session-level, life-cycle changes, attribute changes etc. The implemented interfaces are `javax.servlet.Listener` interface.

Based on @fnt 's responses below, let me try to clarify some more.
Listeners are targeted for lifecycle changes, without having to have a client request coming in. So for one client request, there could be many more lifecycle events may happen before the request is disposed of.
Example:
You want to log all the sessions that timeout. Please note that SesionTimeout is a lifecycle event, which can happen without having the user to do anything. For such a scenario, a listener will be appropriate.

To the question of logging when a request arrives. There is no direct mapping of a new request to an equivalent listener (read lifecycle event) event. And hence for each incoming request if you want to log something, Filter in my opinion is the right thing to use.

This material from Oracle should be able to clarify some more
[Filters and Listeners](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B14099_19/web.1012/b14017/filters.htm)

**Update 17 Mar 2021**
There has been some back and forth in the comments. Trying to clarify.
By definition, a filter will always get invoked. So if i need to log the request ALWAYS, keeping it in filters will ensure that i get the logging. If i put it in listeners, i have to make sure the logging code block is executed in ALL possible listeners. Both approaches will get you the logging that you need, using filters will be more efficient.

HTH

Comment: So if one wants to log something about every request, should one use `ServletRequestListener` or a filter?

Comment: @Ayusman Probably justification is required for this statement

Comment: @fnt since arun asked for logging at per request basis I think filter will fit the bill.

Comment: @Ayusman You still did not explain why filter should be preferred. With request listener one can equally accomplish the same.

Comment: @fnt I don't know if this would be a satisfactory answer for you, but I will try: filters and listeners cater to different category of needs that is based on application boundary. Filters will cater to anything that is entering or leaving the application (an HttpRequest); where as Listeners cater to events with in the container. Visualize filters to be at the edge of an application, and listeners to be inside the application. Example: Web application login can be a "Authorization Filter" where as spring context inititalization is implemented as a lifecycle listener. HTH

Comment: @Ayusman I am sorry, but this does not help. Your reasoning is quite abstract to the topic and it is still not clear why filter should be preferred over listener for logging. Not to mention that you did not provide general principles which can be applied to drive the decision filter/listener.

Comment: @fnt very good point, in my past experiences I have used filters for logging. Why? I think convention more than anything. Listeners can be used for this task as well though.

Comment: @fnt Sorry for late reply. The key here is the question of logging for "every request". I have made some changes in my answer to be able to justify why filter instead of a listener.

Comment: Filters act as pre and post hooks, they can modify the request and response. On the other hand, listeners are more like event handlers, they receive some event and react to it, they don't modify original event.

Comment: @Ayusman Where is the justification really? The question was how to choose between filter and listener when it comes to logging. You merely added the description of how they work and did not address the question. You continue to use words like "appropriate" but fail to explain in which case listener will be inappropriate for logging and why.

Comment: @Anuj Kumar So what? How is that relevant to the particular case of logging?

Comment: The justification lies in the definition. Filters will guarantee that there will be logging whether a particular life cycle event was triggered or not. Since you want to log all requests coming in. It is possible that an incoming request may not necessarily trigger a life cycle event. Or you will end up duplicating the same logging code in every single lifecycle event + you might miss a logging if a particular lifecycle event did not get triggered. HTH

Answer (score 25):

**Filter** is just like a water filter, where incoming (request) and outgoing (response) values will be filtered.

**Listener** is like listening (trigger) - whenever required, I will be performed.

Answer (score 25):

One important difference is often overlooked: while listeners get triggered for an actual physical request, filters work with servlet container dispatches. For one listener invocation there may be multiple filters/servlet invocations.

[image: Listeners vs Filters]

You can specify dispatcher types with the `@WebFilter` annotation:

```
import javax.servlet.DispatcherType;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebFilter;

@WebFilter(servletNames = { "My Servlet" },
    dispatcherTypes = { DispatcherType.REQUEST, DispatcherType.FORWARD })
```

See [Java EE 7 Tutorial: Filtering Requests and Responses](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/servlets006.htm#BNAGB) for more information on filters.
If you still have trouble understanding filters, see [Mapping filters dispatcher types](https://web.archive.org/web/20200519235425/http://otndnld.oracle.co.jp/document/products/as10g/101300/B25221_03/web.1013/b14426/filters.htm) - this is an older J2EE doc, but it goes into more detail.

Answer (score 11):

Text  from [Java EE 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194812/list-of-freely-available-programming-books/4713795#4713795)

**Filter**

Filter is an object which transform the request and response (header as well as content).

**Listeners**

You can monitor and react to events in a servlet's life cycle by defining listener objects whose methods get invoked when life cycle events occur.

Answer (score 8):

After reading all the answers and blogs this is what I got

> **Filter**
>
> A filter is an object that dynamically intercepts requests and
>   responses to transform or use the information contained in the
>   requests or responses.
>
> Filters typically do not themselves create responses but instead
>   provide universal functions that can be "attached" to any type of
>   servlet or JSP page.
>
> The filter is run before rendering view but after controller rendered
>   response.
>
> A Filter is used in the web layer only as it is defined in web.xml.
>
> Filters are more suitable when treating your request/response as a
>   black box system. They'll work regardless of how the servlet is
>   implemented.
>
> Filters are used to perform filtering tasks such as login
>   authentication ,auditing of incoming requests from web pages,
>   conversion, logging, compression, encryption and decryption, input
>   validation etc.
>
> A Servlet Filter is used in the web layer only, you can't use it
>   outside of a web context.

For more detail on filter http://array151.com/blog/servlet-filter/

> **Listener**
>
> Servlet Listener is used for listening to events in a web container,
>   such as when you create a session or place an attribute in a session
>   or if you passivate and activate in another container, to subscribe to
>   these events you can configure listener in web.xml, for example,
>   HttpSessionListener.
>
> Listeners get triggered for an actual physical request that can be
>   attached to events in your app server .With listeners, you can track
>   application-level, session-level, life-cycle changes, attribute
>   changes etc.
>
> You can monitor and react to events in a servlet's life cycle by
>   defining listener objects whose methods get invoked when lifecycle
>   events occur.

For more detail : http://array151.com/blog/servlet-listener/

and here is the difference http://array151.com/blog/difference-between-servlet-filter-and-servlet-listener/

Answer (score 4):

While you can modify the current event object within a listener, you
cannot halt the execution of the current event handler in a listener. 
You also cannot clear the event queue from within a listener. Besides
the imposed differences in capabilities, they are also intended for
different purposes. Listeners tend to focus on interacton between the
event handler and the model, while filters tend to focus on
interaction between the event handler and the controller.

Source : [web](http://lists.topica.com/lists/mach-ii-coldfusion/read/message.html?mid=809889948)

Answer (score 3):

You can easily have a rough idea with the English meaning of those two.

Filter is there to filter the content/resource which coming to/going out from a Servlet. In the other hand, Listener is there, to do some related things when something happen to the web application(listening).

Answer (score 2):

Filter:Filter is simply Filtering the Response and request coming from the clients to the servlet.

Listener:is like a trigger when any trigger is occur it take the action.

Answer (score 1):

In short,

Filter is for the Servlet, intercepting the requests and responses.

Listener is for the Web Application, doing important tasks on events in context-level, session-level etc.

Answer (score 0):

Mostly the answers have this topic covered.  But I find there are a couple practical differences between using `Filter` vs. `ServletRequestListener`.

The 1st is that the listener never gets access to a servlet response object.  Thus, you *have to* use a `Filter` to get access HTTP status returned to the external caller.

Second, all the listeners will have their respective `requestInitialized` methods called before the 1st filter is fired.  Likewise, the listeners' `requestDestroyed` methods are called after the last filter is done.

So, to be sure some request attribute is available to *all* filters, using a listener avoids having to play games with filter ordering.

Likewise, for removing that attribute / tearing down some shared resource, using the listener `requestDestroyed` method ensures all filters are done with it regardless of what order they run.