# When to use ServletRequestListener

Tags: servlets, servlet-listeners

I have not really come across a real use case where you would need to use ServletRequestListener over a Filter. All the things that you can do using ServleletRequestListener can be done using a Filter. So why really use ServletRequestListener ? what am I missing ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between Filter and Listener in Servlet (Java EE)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4720942/difference-between-filter-and-listener-in-servlet-java-ee)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly I would like to tell ypu that there is difference between Filter and Listener .Filter is use to do modification/addition/authentication before requesting and before response.

A filter is an object that can transform a request or alter a response before it reaches to a servlet and can process response before it leaves to a servlet.

One important difference is often overlooked:
 while listeners get triggered for an actual physical request, filters work with servlet container dispatches. For one listener invocation there may be multiple filters/servlet invocations.