# How to manually foward a HTTP request to the default Faces Servlet

Tags: jsf, servlets, jakarta-ee, web.xml

I would like to be able to receive a request on a servlet I made, then analyse the URL and configure the application database based on that, and after the DB is configure forward the request to the regular Faces Servlet.

How should I configure my web.xml? And how can I forward the request to the Faces Servlet?

Here is what I was thinking:

```xml
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>aws</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>servlets.aws</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
<!--    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>-->
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>aws</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

```java
protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");

    System.out.println("configure DB based on URL");

    RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("FacesServlet");
    rd.forward(request, response);        
}
```

However that gives the following error:

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3024949/how-do-i-execute-multiple-servlets-in-sequence.

Comment: Based on the answer of that question I was not able to figure out what I have to do, more specifically how should I configure my web.xml? Sorry if this seems like a silly question but I'm pretty new to servlets and JSF.

Comment: Isn't there a space missing in "FacesServlet"? `request.getRequestDispatcher("FacesServlet");`

Comment: @Selaron: it is wrong anyway iirc. You should not forward to a servlet name (look at the error, there is a relative path in there in front of 'FacesServlet'. You forward to path (that was what I wanted to hint at. I think op needs a filter for his 'aws' code instead of a servlet. Hinted at in another part in the link by talking about independent servlets

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7938138/what-if-url-pattern-matches-multiple-servlets

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2957165/servlet-vs-filter and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4720942/difference-between-filter-and-listener-in-servlet-java-ee

Comment: And https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9812664/what-is-the-difference-between-a-servlet-filter-and-a-servlet-context-listener

Comment: Thank you @Kukeltje

Comment: And? You solved the problem? By using a filter instead of a servlet?

Comment: Sorry for the delay, yes I was able to solve the problem by following the tips you gave me, thank you!